# Add enterkeypress function for adding list in javascript and organize the list style properly in todo

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to add **enterfunction** into Javascript for my TODO list project,in which I can press the enter key and the item should be added, now I am able to add list through add button only.

Secondly, I want to organize The **List** properly for TODO list by giving some style. rightnow it doesn't looks good.

Rightnow my TODOLIST project looks like this https://i.stack.imgur.com/V1j5z.png

```js
var add = document.getElementById('add');
var removeall = document.getElementById('removeall');
var list = document.getElementById('list');


//remove all button

removeall.onclick= function(){
    list.innerHTML= '';
}

//adding a list element

add.onclick = function(){
    addlis(list);
    document.getElementById('userinput').value= '';
    document.getElementById('userinput').focus();
    }

function addlis(targetUl){
    var inputText = document.getElementById('userinput').value;
    var li = document.createElement('li');
    var textNode= document.createTextNode(inputText + ' ');
    var removeButton= document.createElement('button');
    
    
    if(inputText !== ''){
        removeButton.className= 'btn btn-xs btn-danger';
        removeButton.innerHTML= '&times;';
        removeButton.setAttribute('onclick','removeMe(this)');
      
    
    li.appendChild(textNode); //onebelowanother
    li.appendChild(removeButton); 
    targetUl.appendChild(li);
} else{
    alert("Please enter a TODO");
}
}

function removeMe(item){
    var p = item.parentElement;
    p.parentElement.removeChild(p);
}
```

```css
body{
    font-family: 'EB Garamond', serif;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    background-color: beige;
}

h1{
    margin: 40px;
}

#userinput{
    width: 350px;
    height: 35px;
    display: inline-block;
}

.btn{
    margin: 20px 5px;
}

.form-control{
    margin: 0 auto;
}

ul{
    list-style: none;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
 <meta charset="utf-8">
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
 <link rel="stylesheet" media="screen" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/TodoStyle.css">
 <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=EB+Garamond&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">


 <title>My Online TODO List App</title>

 
</head>

<body>

 <div class="container-fluid text-center">
     <h1>My First working TODO</h1>
     <input type="text" id="userinput" class="form-control" placeholder="what you need to do" onkeydown="return searchKeyPress(event);">
     <button class="btn btn-success" id="add">Add a TODO</button>
     <button class="btn btn-danger" id="removeall">REMOVE ALL TODO</button>
     <ul id="list">
      <li class="list"></li> 
    
    
     </ul>
     
     

 </div>

 <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
 <script src="js/Todo.js"></script>

 

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just wrap all the `input`s and `button`s inside a `form` tag like this:

```html
<form id="...">
<input type="text" id="userinput" class="form-control" placeholder="what you need to do" onkeydown="return searchKeyPress(event);">
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-success" id="add">Add a TODO</button>
</form>
```

and replace this:

```js
add.onclick = function(){...})
```

with

```js
form = document.getElementBy...
form.addEventListener('submit', function() {...})
```

Also try to avoid writing `add.onclick` and use `addEventListener`. That way you can have multiple listeners, remove them easily, and overall have more control.

Answer (score 0):

Use event listener for key press on your input (13 is the enter key):

```
var input = document.getElementById("userinput");

input.addEventListener("keyup", function(event) {
  if (event.keyCode === 13) {
    event.preventDefault();
    searchKeyPress(event);
  }
});
```